# The Fastest Method of Solving System of Non-linear Equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, processing-efficiency, bigdata

Assume we have three equations:

```
 eq1 =  x1 + (x1 - x2) * t - X         == 0;
 eq2 =  z1 + (z1 - z2) * t - Z         == 0;
 eq3 = ((X-x1)/a)^2 + ((Z-z1)/b)^2 - 1 == 0;
```

while six of known variables are:

```
a  =  42 ; 
b  =  12 ;
x1 =  316190;
z1 =  234070;
x2 =  316190;
z2 =  234070;
```

So we are looking for three unknown variables that are:

```
X , Z and t
```

I wrote two method to solve it. But, since I need to run these code for 5.7 million data, it become really slow.

**Method one (using "solve"):**

```
tic
S  = solve( eq1 , eq2  , eq3 , X , Z , t ,...
           'ReturnConditions', true, 'Real', true);
toc
X = double(S.X(1)) 
Z = double(S.Z(1)) 
t = double(S.t(1))
```

results of method one:

```
X =  316190;
Z =  234060;
t = -2.9280;
Elapsed time is 0.770429 seconds.
```

**Method two (using "fsolve"):**

```
coeffs = [a,b,x1,x2,z1,z2];       % Known parameters
x0     = [ x2 ; z2 ; 1 ].';       % Initial values for iterations
f_d = @(x0) myfunc(x0,coeffs);    % f_d considers x0 as variables
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','none');
tic
M = fsolve(f_d,x0,options);
toc
```

results of method two:

```
 X =  316190; % X = M(1)
 Z =  234060; % Z = M(2)
 t = -2.9280; % t = M(3)
Elapsed time is 0.014 seconds.
```

Although, the second method is faster, but it still needs to be improved. Please let me know if you have a better solution for that. Thanks

---

*** extra information:**
if you are interested to know what those 3 equations are, the first two are equations of a line in 2D and the third equation is an ellipse equation. I need to find the intersection of the line with the ellipse. Obviously, we have two points as result. But, let's forget about the second answer for simplicity.

Comment: First, your method one does not return the solution you indicate. Please edit to provide actual code and values. Second, the outputs for both methods are identical as currently written – what do you mean by "but it still needs to be improved"? Have you tried adjusting the tolerances or other properties for `fsolve`?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion it's to use the second approce,which it's the recommended by matlab for nonlinear equation system.
Declare a M-function

```
function Y=mysistem(X)
%X(1) = X
%X(2) = t
%X(3) = Z
a  =  42 ; 
b  =  12 ;
x1 =  316190;
z1 =  234070;
x2 =  316190;
z2 =  234070;
Y(1,1) = x1 + (x1 - x2) * X(2) - X(1);
Y(2,1) = z1 + (z1 - z2) * X(2) - X(3);
Y(3,1) = ((X-x1)/a)^2 + ((Z-z1)/b)^2 - 1;
end
```

Then for solving use

```
x0     = [ x2 , z2 , 1 ];
M = fsolve(@mysistem,x0,options);
```

If you may want to reduce the default precision by changing `StepTolerance` (default 1e-6).
Also for more increare you may want to use the jacobian matrix for greater efficencies.
For more reference take a look in official documentation:
[fsolve](http://it.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html)  [Nonlinear Equations with Analytic Jacobian](http://it.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-equations-with-analytic-jacobian.html)

Basically giving the solver the Jacobian matrix of the system(and special options) you can increase method efficency.